# Pass contents of sha256sum from user input into a variable

Tags: bash

I'm having trouble putting the contents of sha256sum from user input into a variable:

```
echo "Your password please"

read -e pass

pass256=${pass | sha256sum}

printf "Password SHA256 is "$pass256"\n\n"

exit
```

After execution the script says:

```
./password_hashing: line 12: ${pass | sha256sum}: bad substitution
```

I have tried to enclose the complete command between parentheses, without curly_brackets, between single quotes.

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.
That being said the `${}` is not the same as [$()](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
pass256=$(sha256sum<<<"$pass")
```

or if you don't want the trailing `*-`,

```
read pass256 _ <<< $(sha256sum<<<"$pass")
```